# Pyplot - shift position of y-axis ticks and its data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, axis

[image: Visual summary of what I want to do]

Using pyplot, how do I modify my plot to change the vertical position of my yticks? E.g. in my plot above, I want to move 'Promoter' down and 'CDS' up (along with their 'lines' in the plot).

For the above plot, my x-data is a range of numbers, while my y-data is categorical. Code to reproduce plot as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_CDS = list(range(661, 668))
y_CDS = ["CDS"] * len(x_CDS)

x_RBS = list(range(649, 656))
y_RBS = ["RBS"] * len(x_RBS)

x_prom = list(range(570, 601))
y_prom = ["Promoter"] * len(x_prom)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
plt.xlim(1, 3002)
plt.xlabel('Nucleotide position')

plt.plot(x_CDS, y_CDS, label='CDS')
plt.plot(x_RBS, y_RBS, label='RBS')
plt.plot(x_prom, y_prom, label='Promoter')
```

Note: the lines in this case are quite small, but the ranges can be made larger for convenience.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not producing anything due to `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'CDS'`. Make sure you paste the code which produces a plot for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default matplotlib produces some 5% margins on each side of the data. Here it seems you want to increase this margin for the vertical direction. Maybe you want 40%, i.e. `plt.margins(y=0.4)`?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_CDS = list(range(661, 668))
y_CDS = ["CDS"] * len(x_CDS)

x_RBS = list(range(649, 656))
y_RBS = ["RBS"] * len(x_RBS)

x_prom = list(range(570, 601))
y_prom = ["Promoter"] * len(x_prom)

plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

plt.xlabel('Nucleotide position')

plt.plot(x_CDS, y_CDS, label='CDS')
plt.plot(x_RBS, y_RBS, label='RBS')
plt.plot(x_prom, y_prom, label='Promoter')

plt.margins(y=0.4)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The advantage of using `margins` here instead of changing the `ylim` is that you do not need to count the categories to find out what useful value to choose for the limits. But of course you may equally change the limits via `plt.ylim(-0.8,2.8)` toc achieve the same plot.

Answer (score 1):

`plt.margins(y=10)` should provide a padding on the top and bottom of the y-axis ticks. I am using y=10 as an example, please tweak it as necessary. Hope, this is what you were looking for.